# Large(ish) Application that Edits a lot of Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on an application that includes many inputs which are all part of one large data tree.

The data looks similar to this:

```
data: {
  input_1: "Text",
  input_2: "etc",
  ...
  input_n: "foo"
}
```

Each input component receives - as a prop - the key for the location of the data it is supposed to display
and modify (`<InputComponent data={data['input_1']} objectKey={'input_1'} onChange={this.updateData} />`).

There is some validation that occurs inside of the component itself but basically `this.onChange` is debounced and called
when changing the text.

I'm handling onChange in a way similar to this:

```
onChange = (newInput, objectKey) => {
  const {data} = this.state;

  const newData = {
    ...data,
    [objectKey]: newInput
  };

  this.setState({
    data: newData
  });
};
```

I'm noticing some slowdowns and laggy behavior when updating entries. This is - at least as far as I understand it - becuase
each component that is "hooked into" this data are re-rendering.

Is this a silly approach? If so, what would be a better one? It's not *that* bad yet but I'm anticipating this getting worse
as it increases in size/complexity.

Comment: How many input elements are we talking about here?

Comment: Currently I'm at around ~20 or so inputs per page

Comment: I made a fiddle based on your explanation, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k2hxxccs/). I had to change the arguments for the `onChange` function though because I don't know exactly what you are sending in. Either way, it's very smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach, any criticize is welcome since I am also looking a better way to my application with a similar issue.

I would make `InputComponent` as a `PureComponent` with an internal state for the current input value. `PureComponent` will automatically do the shallow-compare to your `state`. If your `InputComponent` is more complex with `state` consist of arrays or deep objects, you should manually implement your `shouldComponentUpdate` yourself.

The `onChange` would simply update its internal state, then `debounce` the call `props.onChange`

```
onChange(val) {
  this.setState(val);
  debounce(this.props.onChange(val));
}
```

With this way, the update seems smoother and after that, the parent's value is also updated accordingly without re-render and update the children `InputComponent`.

Comment: What is the best practice in terms of setting the initial state if it comes from the parent? I've always thought that doing something like `this.setState({data: this.props.data})` in `componentDidMount` was not advised?

Comment: It is not recommended to call `setState` in `componentDidMount` anyway, it will trigger another update extra lifecycle. You can initialize your state within constructor. `super(props); this.state = { val: props.data };`